# iterate through all fields and then validate on blur using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a couple of text boxes in the page and I am trying to do some validations on blur of the field. If validation fails, error is displayed and the field is highlighted. This is working correctly for blur of a single field element. Initially I thought its coz teh flag was not set correctly. But I think the code can validate only a single element at a time, thats why the flag is always returning false. So I need the function to be extended for all the fields on blur of those.

```
var validatorFlag = true;
var indFlag = 0;

var validators = {
allowaplhawithaposonly:function(val) {
    return /^[a-zA-Z'\s]+$/i.test(val);
},
allowaplhanumwithaposonly:function(val) {
    return /^[\w'\s]+$/i.test(val);
},
allownospace: function (val) {
    return !/\s/.test(val);
}
};

$('#submit_form .required').blur(function () {
var input = $(this);
var classReturn = true;

input.next('ul.innererrormessages').remove();
input.removeClass('required_IE');
if (!input.val()) {alert("no val");
                   input.removeClass('valid');
                   input.addClass('required_IE');
                   var $msg = $(this).attr('title');
                   input.after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>');
                   validatorFlag = false;
                  }
else{alert("val present");
     if(this.className) {
         var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
         for(var p in classes) {
             if(classes[p] in validators) {
                 classReturn = classReturn && validators[classes[p]] (input.val());
             }
         }alert("classReturn "+classReturn);
     }
     if(classReturn == false){
         input.removeClass('valid');
         input.addClass('required_IE');
         var $msg = input.attr('title');
         input.after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+$msg+'</li></ul>');
         validatorFlag = false;
         indFlag = 1;
     }
     else{
         if(indFlag != 1){
             validatorFlag = true;
         }
         else{
             validatorFlag = false;
         }
     }

    }alert("validatorFlag "+validatorFlag); //This is always returning false

});

$('#submit_form').submit(function() {
if(validatorFlag)
{
    returnValue = true;
}
else{
    returnValue = false;
}
return returnValue;
});
```

I need to check the class validations for all the fields on blur of the field. But if I use the above code, it will validate correctly for one field. On blur of the second element, the flag will not be set properly. So is it possible to extend the above function for on blur of all the fields?

Comment: It's not an answer to this question but I'd seriously suggest using something like: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation It will make your code a lot simpler and save you time and effort, why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: yes I know..This is time consuming..But this is the one we have been using..So I am finding difficulty in implementing as well :(